# SLAX behaves differently when booted via PXE vs LiveCD from the same iso

Tags: linux, citrix, iso, live-cd

I have a SLAX iso  that I have created that is used only to run the Citrix ICA client.  The ICA client is started in /root/.xinitrc, and when booting from the LiveCD it works properly.  /root/.xinitrc is in the rootcopy folder on the iso.  However, when booting via pxe, with the from=http://server_ip/slax.iso, /root/.xinitrc doesn't exist and the ICA client isn't started.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening when PXE booting.

Comment: I've tried creating new lzm modules but anything that I try to put into the root directory seems to be ignored when pxe booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why this was happening, but even though I had from=http://server_ip/slax.iso, it was actually pulling from an old slax directory that was on the server.  So, the only thing I can guess is that the from line was getting truncated and/or split at the .iso.